# Should i boot my system into live desktop to do diagnostics

Tags: boot

Basically my system has flipped into ro now the advise is to check the logs but to do that I need to install smartmontools but I cnt because of ro so should I boot the drive with live usb so I can run diagnostics on it or is there another way I can do it on the broken live system

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said, I would:

1. Boot to the live USB, and try Ubuntu without installing
2. Once in there, open a file manager, should be able to see and access the drives of your new installation that is not working.
3. Look for log files under /var/log - you can open them with a text editor on the live USB or command line.